# Finite Ordinal Example

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I apologize if this question is too simple, but its answer would be a lot of help in my understanding of ordinal numbers.

What is the numerical ordinal number associated with the well-ordered set A={a,b}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $2$. In fact, if $A$ is a well ordered set with $n$ elements, where $n$ is finite, then its associated ordinal must be $n$.